# Do I have to unlock the elevators in order?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

In tiny death star, do I have to buy all the elevators to unlock the next one, or can I somehow unlock them all? I would not like to waste bux on elevators that I am upgrading away from immediately.

Comment: Appears that way, but I don't have enough Imperial bux to know if it's only showing the next level because I don't have enough to afford the others. I bought the first elevator, and now it's locked, and the second one is available for 75, with the following ones locked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I gathered they unlock one elevator at the time. I spent months playing Tiny Tower and the game dynamics is very similar here, so although I started building my death star yesterday, I upgraded my elevator and then it unlocked the next upgrade for 75 bux :-)

UPDATE: I upgraded to the elevator for 75 bux and it again unlocked the next lift for 125, again only the one.

Comment: Yeah it seems like this is the way to go, earning bux ingame is just too sloooow.

Comment: I call it a challenge. It's too easy to just buy them :-) I already saved another 90 bux, so I think it's not that slow... In Tiny Tower we used to get 2 bux for landing a dream job, here it's only 1 bux, but still there are other ways to make bux...

Comment: Worst part.  I finally saved 499 Bux for the final upgrade, and they lowered the PPM rating on it!